# AS3 - What is the best, or recommended way of wrapping Bitmaps into Sprite containers?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm learning AS3 using `FlashDevelop` IDE and `Flex` to compile.

I add images by creating a `Bitmap` class and then embedding a .png in the code, example:

Enemy.as

```
package enemies 
{

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent

[Embed(source="../../assets/gardengnome.png")]

public class Enemy extends Bitmap 
{
    public function Enemy() 
    {
        trace("enemy constructed");
    }
}

}
```

I have learned that in order to be able to handle `MouseEvent` I need to put this `Bitmap` into a `Sprite` container.

Now, not knowing any better this is the way I have done it:

I create a new variable to hold `enemyContainer` in `Main.as` and add it to the stage:

```
package 
{
 import enemies.Enemy;
 import enemies.EnemyContainer;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import Player.Player;

 public class Main extends Sprite 
 {
   public var enemyContainer:EnemyContainer = new EnemyContainer();

     public function Main():void 
 {
   addChild(enemyContainer);
 }
}
}
```

And then the `EnemyContainer` class calls the `Enemy` `Bitmap` that holds the graphic and adds it to itself as a child:

```
package enemies 
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent


public class EnemyContainer extends Sprite 
{
    private var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy();

    public function EnemyContainer() 
    {
        trace("enemyContainer constructed");

        addChild(enemy);

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
    }

    private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Clicked Enemy");
    }

}

}
```

I don't have enough experience yet to see any problems doing it this way. I can change the graphic in the `Enemy` `Bitmap` class without having to deal with anything else, and `Main.as` handles positioning of the `EnemyContainer`.

However, if there is a recommended, or more efficient way to handle this I'd like to learn it now before I get into a habit. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This is good.  Nothing inefficient about it if you need the sprite wrapper

Comment: Only tip would be to instantiate your enemy in the constructor and not in the variable declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example it looks like you are creating 3 classes to implement the bitmap inside a sprite:

- Enemy extends Bitmap
- EnemyContainer extends Sprite
- Main extends    Sprite

Your method is totally valid, and you will not have a problem with it. In fact, there is no one best way to do this. What is best depends on the context. However, you may find it more easy to manage if you implement Enemy as part of EnemyContainer so that you have only two classes:

- Main
- EnemyContainer

In EmemyContainer you make a private class for the enemy bitmap like so:

```
package enemies 
{

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent


public class EnemyContainer extends Sprite 
{

    [Embed(source="../../assets/gardengnome.png")]
    private EnemyBitmap:Class;

    public function EnemyContainer() 
    {
        trace("enemyContainer constructed");

        addChild(new EnemyBitmap()); // Creates a new instance of your bitmap class.

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);


    }

    private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Clicked Enemy");
    }

}

}
```

You may additionally find it helpful to use the `mouseChildren` and `buttonMode` property of the Sprite, but that will depend on how you want the mouse interaction to work.

== In reply To Comments ==

To position the bitmap on registration center:

```
var temp:Bitmap = new EnemyBitmap() as Bitmap;
temp.x = -temp.width/2;
temp.y = -temp.height/2;
addChild(temp);
```

Comment: One question, though. If I wanted to be able to place the bitmap in a specific position of the container (for example at -width/2 and -height/2 to simulate having the bitmap with a centered registration point), how to go about assigning a variable to it?

I've simply done `var enemy = addChild(new EnemyBitmap());` , but the compiler wants me to give the variable a type, and the only one I've figured out that satisfies the compiler is `DisplayObject`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is OK

If you want less classes you could also embed the bitmap in your container class

```
public class Enemy extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source="../../assets/gardengnome.png")]
    private var assetClass:Class;

    private var asset:Bitmap;

    public function Enemy()
    {
       //init the class
       //do this in a seperate method, because the constructor is executed by a just in time compiler. Means less code better performance.
       init();
    }

    private function init():void
    {
        asset = new assetClass();
        addChild(asset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A noble effort, but try this instead as a best practice:

```
public class Enemy extends Sprite 
{
    public function Enemy() 
    {
      var bmp = new EnemyBitmap();   // what is currently your Enemy class should be EnemyBitmap
      addChild(bmp);
    }
}
```

This technique is called "implementation" where the desired class (Bitmap) is loaded into a container instead of the container extending the Bitmap class itself ("inheritance").

Comment: This is exactly what he is doing, except you've changed the names around and are extending MovieClip (for some unknown reason) instead of Sprite.

Comment: Though I do agree renaming his `Enemy` class to `EnemyBitmap` is clearer to understand.

Comment: `Enemy` extended `Bitmap` before so it could not receive `MouseEvent`s. Now that extends MovieClip it can receive `MouseEvent`s without a problematic `EnemyContainer` holding them all. `Sprite` would also work equally well.

Comment: All you've done though is renamed what was `EnemyContainer` to `Enemy`, and what was `Enemy` to `EnemyBitmap`.   Sprite will work better (not just as well) because the question is about efficiency and Sprite has less overhead than MovieClip

Comment: As an aside to what @LondonDrugs_MediaServices is saying, you should **never** use `MovieClip` unless you have a precise reason as to why you need the TimeLine feature (or need a dynamic class). Other than that, you should **always** use `Sprite` as your basic `DisplayObjectContainer`

Comment: Agreed there is no known reason to extend MovieClip.